# How to remove extra <p> </p> tags in wordpress post and pages?

Tags: wordpress

I have use WordPress filter but i can't remove all extra **`<p></p>`** tags.

This **`<p></p>`** tags adding  in last of page and post content.

But i want to remove all **`<p></p>`** tags in WordPress post and page view

Comment: Why not use strip_tags() function if you want to remove all tags from content? Try this.

Comment: I have already use strip_tags() function. But all extra tag can't remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, wherever you have `echo get_the_content($params)` posted (maybe just content.php, depends on theme), do:

```
echo preg_replace(array('<p>','</p>'),array('',''),get_the_content($params),1)
```

That will replace any occurrences of `<p>` with the empty string `''`; likewise for `</p>`.

Doing this will not matter whether you author the content in HTML or Visual modes, if it's there, it'll remove it; if not, it won't break it.

If you just don't like the style wherever you have `<p></p>` tags, then post `p{}` from style.css, and describe how you want it to look - is it the gap between paragraphs you want smaller or bigger, for example?

Answer (score 1):

Please use this line of code instead of `the_content();` / `the_excerpt();` then it will works fine.

for content

```
<?php remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' ); the_content(); ?>
```

for excerpt

```
<?php remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' ); the_content(); ?>
```

Hope so it will help. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Please try with below code:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );

                   OR

remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

It will remove all extra `<p>` tags from content.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello Chandresh, i have use this filter but two of <p></p> tags adding in my shortocode page. I want to remove all <p></p> tags.This tags are add in after content block.

Comment: @harimaliya you have to use like that <?php remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' ); the_content(); ?> then it will works perfectly. hope it will helpfull. Thanks